# Enhanced Video Player For Pc

Tags: video, image-processing, video-player

Several years ago, I used a program called "Neuview Media Player" in Windows OS. Basically, it's enhance the quality of video in real time ( by image resampling, sharping, color adjustment etc. ).

[image: RealTime Image Processing]

But however this player is very old, not supported new codecs etc.
**Do you know any program like enchance video quality in real time ?** Im using windows and linux(ubuntu).

I found Splash 2.0 premium media player, but it's not making any difference, it's not like Neuview.

Comment: Have you played with the Sharpen tool in VLC (and others in the same config area) - it may do what you want.

Comment: @ivanivan Thanks for your suggestion. I'm looking some kind of dynamic-optimizer and it's not all about sharping, player/plugin should correct colors etc too.